# SSH without portforward

Tags: linux, ssh, tunnel

I have a raspberry pi lying around in my dorm room. It's connected to campus internet which has all ports closed and I obviously don't have any access or permission to port forwarding. Now I want to ssh to the raspberry pi but this isn't possible since I can't port forward. I do  however have a cheap vps doing nothing. Is there a way to make the pi connect to the vps and then use the vps as some sort of tunnel to ssh to the raspberry pi without having any port forwarding done?

Comment: What do you mean by VPS? Virtual private server? So you do not have a direct access to the RPI but you have access to the VPS and the VPS have access to the RPI? Then answer is yes, on the VPS you can run a SSH server and do SSH port forwarding through the VPS.

Comment: note, this is called 'reverse tunneling' http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_connection so you know what to look up.

Comment: The reverse tunneling is indeed what I was looking for, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

If you can ssh out of the Pi, you can use `-R 1234:localhost:22` and then `ssh vps -p 1234`:

```
 -R [bind_address:]port:host:hostport
         Specifies that the given port on the remote (server) host is to
         be forwarded to the given host and port on the local side.  This
         works by allocating a socket to listen to port on the remote
         side, and whenever a connection is made to this port, the connec-
         tion is forwarded over the secure channel, and a connection is
         made to host port hostport from the local machine.

         Port forwardings can also be specified in the configuration file.
         Privileged ports can be forwarded only when logging in as root on
         the remote machine.  IPv6 addresses can be specified by enclosing
         the address in square braces or using an alternative syntax:
         [bind_address/]host/port/hostport.

         By default, the listening socket on the server will be bound to
         the loopback interface only.  This may be overridden by specify-
         ing a bind_address.  An empty bind_address, or the address '*',
         indicates that the remote socket should listen on all interfaces.
         Specifying a remote bind_address will only succeed if the
         server's GatewayPorts option is enabled (see sshd_config(5)).

         If the port argument is '0', the listen port will be dynamically
         allocated on the server and reported to the client at run time.
```